# libGDX Framebuffer Alpha Issues

Tags: libgdx, alpha, framebuffer

I'm having issues with the libGDX FrameBuffer and Alpha. Below are two images of the expected result and the actual result. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and how can I correct it. Here is the code:

```
FrameBuffer buffer;
Sprite sprite;

SpriteBatch batch;
Texture texture1;
Texture texture2;
Texture texture3;
Sprite texture2Sprite;

@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    texture1 = new Texture("1.png");
    texture2 = new Texture("2.png");
    texture3 = new Texture("3.png");

    texture2Sprite = new Sprite(texture2);
    texture2Sprite.setAlpha(0.5f);
    texture2Sprite.setPosition(100, 100);

    buffer = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);
    sprite = new Sprite(buffer.getColorBufferTexture());
    sprite.flip(false, true);
}

public void createFBO()
{
    buffer.begin();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(texture1, 0f, 0f);

    texture2Sprite.draw(batch);

    batch.end();
    buffer.end();
}

@Override
public void render () {

    createFBO();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    batch.enableBlending();
    batch.draw(texture3, 200, 200);
    sprite.draw(batch);

    batch.end();
}
```

[image: Expected Result]
Expected Result

[image: Actual Result]
Actual Result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had pretty much the same issue with semi-transparent colours in the `FrameBuffer`, the problem and solution you can find on my badlogic forum topic [here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=22667).

Basically, you need to draw to your `FrameBuffer` in a pre-multiplied alpha state. You do this by creating a custom fragment shader (my full code is on the topic). Then you set your blending mode to match (GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA).

Then draw your sprite using the same blend function but default shader. You should end up with something like this;

```
public void createFBO(){
    buffer.begin();
    batch.begin();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.setShader(pmaShaderProgram); //pre-multiplied alpha ShaderProgram
    batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    batch.draw(texture1, 0f, 0f);
    texture2Sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.setShader(null); //default ShaderProgram
    batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); //default blend mode

    batch.end();
    buffer.end();
}

@Override
public void render () {
    createFBO();

    batch.begin();
    batch.enableBlending();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.draw(texture3, 200, 200);

    batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    batch.end();
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks it worked perfectly... However I've got one more follow up. Say I wanted to draw something to the FrameBuffer that has an alpha component but also uses another shader program. How would I go about that?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I think the only way around your next issue is to create another version of your other custom shader and modify it to draw pre-multiplied alpha. I imagine the majority of shaders you can simply add the necessary line at the end; `gl_FragColor.rgb *= gl_FragColor.a;`

Comment: The forum link is long dead. What is that custom shader exactly?